# Android parsing JSON in UTF-8

Tags: android, json, utf-8, encode

I'm using a webservice to make a some dynamic activity. Everything works fine except UTF-8 encoding. I've tried to encode JSON in UTF-8, but I haven't been successful so far. Here is my Servicehandler which includes UTF-8 encoding:

```
 try {
        // http client
        DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpEntity httpEntity = null;
        HttpResponse httpResponse = null;

        // Checking http request method type
        if (method == POST) {
            HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
            // adding post params
            if (params != null) {
                httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params));
            }

            httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);

        } else if (method == GET) {
            // appending params to url
            if (params != null) {
                String paramString = EntityUtils.toString(httpEntity, HTTP.UTF_8);
                url += "?" + paramString;
            }
            HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(url);

            httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpGet);

        }
        httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
        response = EntityUtils.toString(httpEntity);
```

Here's my doInBackground method:

```
  @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
        // Creating service handler class instance
        ServiceHandler sh = new ServiceHandler();

        // Making a request to url and getting response
        String jsonStr = sh.makeServiceCall(url, ServiceHandler.GET);

        Log.d("Response: ", "> " + jsonStr);

        if (jsonStr != null) {
            try {
                JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(jsonStr);

                // Getting JSON Array node
                contacts = jsonObj.getJSONArray(TAG_CONTACTS);


                // looping through All Contacts
                for (int i = 0; i < contacts.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject c = contacts.getJSONObject(i);

                    String id = c.getString(TAG_ID);
                    String name = c.getString(TAG_NAME);
                    String adress = c.getString(TAG_ADRESS);



                    // tmp hashmap for single contact
                    HashMap<String, String> contact = new HashMap<String, String>();



                    // adding each child node to HashMap key => value
                    contact.put(TAG_ID, id);
                    contact.put(TAG_NAME, name);
                    contact.put(TAG_ADRESS, adress);



                    // adding contact to contact list
                    contactList.add(contact);
                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        } else {
            Log.e("ServiceHandler", "Couldn't get any data from the url");
        }

        return null;
    }
```

Comment: Please better describe your problem. What do you expect to happen? What happens instead? Do you have a problem with sending or receiving? Does it crash? Doesn't it compile? What's the error message?

Comment: Some characters like ı or İ or Ş or any others do not work properly.Instead of them any other characters has been seen.

Comment: And it doesnt crash works fine.Just I want to make my json utf-8 encoding.

Comment: from the looks of it, it could as easily be your server that is not handling the encoding

Comment: Most likely, the server doesn't properly encode them, does not provide the information about the encoding or provides the wrong one. Try to use `EntityUtils.toString(httpEntity, "UTF-8")` instead of `EntityUtils.toString(httpEntity)`.